# How to mimic LIMIT 1 in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server

Suppose two tables with the following:

```
insert into tmp1 values(12345) // orderid
insert into tmp1 values(54321)
insert into tmp1 values(77777)

insert into tmp2 values(12345, 1) // orderid, code
insert into tmp2 values(12345, 2)
insert into tmp2 values(54321, 1)
insert into tmp2 values(77777, 1)
insert into tmp2 values(77777, 2)
insert into tmp2 values(77777, 3)
```

and then I write the following:

```
select a.orderid from tmp1 a
inner join tmp2 b on b.orderid = a.orderid where b.code in (1,2)
```

Is there a way I can just get on output:

```
12345,
54321,
77777
```

This would be for a report where I just want to know the order numbers without the replication due to the inner join, although the inner join is important because there's more than a few codes to choose from.

Comment: Isn't this simply `DISTINCT`?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.orderid 
FROM   tmp1 a 
       INNER JOIN tmp2 b 
               ON b.orderid = a.orderid 
WHERE  b.code IN ( 1, 2 )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct a.orderid from tmp1 a inner join tmp2 b
on b.orderid = a.orderid where b.code in (1,2)
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I must have been REALLY tired to forget the DISTINCT keyword. I have no idea where my brain was! Thanks for bringing me back from the netherworld!

Answer (score -1):

You can use UNION operator like this -

```
Select orderid from tmp1
Union 
Select orderid from tmp2 Where code In (1,2);
```

Or you can also use Inner Join with the Distinct -

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT t1.Orderid
FROM tmp1 t1
INNER JOIN tmp2 t2 
ON t1.orderid = t2.orderid
WHERE t2.code IN (1, 2);
```

Comment: The union approach could list orderids that do not have b.code in (1,2). Every orderid would be listed.

Answer (score -1):

Avoid any join:

```
select distinct t2.orderid
from temp2 t2
where t2.code in (1,2)
```

Use exists (a "semi-join"):

```
select t1.orderid
from tmp1 t1
    where exists (
    select null
    from temp2 t2
    where t1.orderid = t2.orderid and t2.code in (1,2)
    )
```

Use the windowing function ROW_NUMBER():

```
select d.* from (
    select t2.orderid
         , row_number() over(partition by t2.orderid order by t2.code) rn
    from temp2 t2
    where t2.code in (1,2)
    ) d
where d.rn = 1
```

This third option may seem overkill for this simple example, but the technique is particularly useful for finding information such as "first" or "last" or "earliest" or "latest".